# How to Update SQL in ASP.Net?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, linq

I have an `UPDATE` SQL Server stored procedure `XemDiem_Upate`. Now if I only have 1 parameter like `@month_1`, how can I update using ASP.NET?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE XemDiem_Update
    (@month_1 NVARCHAR(MAX),
     @month_2 NVARCHAR(MAX),
     @month_3 NVARCHAR(MAX),
     @month_4 NVARCHAR(MAX),
     @month_5 NVARCHAR(MAX),
     @month_6 NVARCHAR(MAX),
     @month_7 NVARCHAR(MAX),
     @month_8 NVARCHAR(MAX),
     @month_9 NVARCHAR(MAX),
     @month_10 NVARCHAR(MAX),
     @month_11 NVARCHAR(MAX),
     @month_12 NVARCHAR(MAX),
     @user_id INT)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE XemDiem 
    SET month_1 = @month_1, month_2 = @month_2, 
        month_3 = @month_3, month_4 = @month_4, 
        month_5 = @month_5, month_6 = @month_6, 
        month_7 = @month_7, month_8 = @month_8, 
        month_9 = @month_9, month_10 = @month_10, 
        month_11 = @month_11, month_12 = @month_12 
    WHERE user_id = @user_id
END
```

Comment: If you have to update only month 1, then you can’t use the stored procedure, otherwise all other month are set to null, if nullable or you’ll get an error. So either you create a different procedure, or you use a direct update-statement. Furthermore, there are many ways to execute db-commands in asp.net. Are you using a OR-Mapper like EntityFramework?

Comment: well i change to @month_1 nvarchar(max)=null

Comment: How are you connecting? Are you using Entity Framework? You say you want to use LINQ - add this to the question.

Comment: What’s your best not working attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your parameter optional:

`@month_1  NVARCHAR(max) = NULL`

Update only when parameter not supplied

`month_1 = CASE WHEN @month_1 IS NULL THEN month_1 ELSE @month_1 END`

Here is sample implementation:

```
CREATE PROC XemDiem_Update(@month_1  NVARCHAR(max) = NULL, 
                           @month_2  NVARCHAR(max) = NULL, 
                           @month_3  NVARCHAR(max) = NULL, 
                           @month_4  NVARCHAR(max) = NULL, 
                           @month_5  NVARCHAR(max) = NULL, 
                           @month_6  NVARCHAR(max) = NULL, 
                           @month_7  NVARCHAR(max) = NULL, 
                           @month_8  NVARCHAR(max) = NULL, 
                           @month_9  NVARCHAR(max) = NULL, 
                           @month_10 NVARCHAR(max) = NULL, 
                           @month_11 NVARCHAR(max) = NULL, 
                           @month_12 NVARCHAR(max) = NULL, 
                           @user_id  INT) 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      UPDATE Xemdiem 
      SET    month_1 = CASE WHEN @month_1 IS NULL THEN month_1 ELSE @month_1 END, 
             month_2 = CASE WHEN @month_2 IS NULL THEN month_2 ELSE @month_2 END, 
             month_3 = CASE WHEN @month_3 IS NULL THEN month_3 ELSE @month_3 END, 
             month_4 = CASE WHEN @month_4 IS NULL THEN month_4 ELSE @month_4 END, 
             month_5 = CASE WHEN @month_5 IS NULL THEN month_5 ELSE @month_5 END, 
             month_6 = CASE WHEN @month_6 IS NULL THEN month_6 ELSE @month_6 END, 
             month_7 = CASE WHEN @month_7 IS NULL THEN month_7 ELSE @month_7 END, 
             month_8 = CASE WHEN @month_8 IS NULL THEN month_8 ELSE @month_8 END, 
             month_9 = CASE WHEN @month_9 IS NULL THEN month_9 ELSE @month_9 END, 
             month_10 = CASE WHEN @month_10 IS NULL THEN month_10 ELSE @month_10 END, 
             month_11 = CASE WHEN @month_11 IS NULL THEN month_11 ELSE @month_11 END, 
             month_12 = CASE WHEN @month_12 IS NULL THEN month_12 ELSE @month_12 END 
      WHERE  user_id = @user_id 
  END
```

Comment: ok tks but idk how to update by asp .net. I using LinQ to SQL